# QCustomPlot and iRangeDrag on second right yAxis

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

I'm trying to make the right axis draggable.

Right now using one of the site examples im able to make the first `yAxis` draggable by double clicking on it.

```
void MainWindow::mousePress()
{
// if an axis is selected, only allow the direction of that axis to be dragged
// if no axis is selected, both directions may be dragged

if (ui->customPlot->xAxis->selectedParts().testFlag(QCPAxis::spAxis))
    ui->customPlot->axisRect()->setRangeDrag(ui->customPlot->xAxis->orientation());
else if (ui->customPlot->yAxis->selectedParts().testFlag(QCPAxis::spAxis))
    ui->customPlot->axisRect()->setRangeDrag(ui->customPlot->yAxis->orientation());
else if (ui->customPlot->yAxis2->selectedParts().testFlag(QCPAxis::spAxis))
    ui->customPlot->axisRect()->setRangeDrag(ui->customPlot->yAxis2->orientation());
else
    ui->customPlot->axisRect()->setRangeDrag(Qt::Horizontal|Qt::Vertical);
}
```

My graphs has 2 lines, each with a different `yAxis`.
What I would like to achieve is the same draggable effect on the second (on the right) `yAxis` which is called `yAxis2`.
With the code below even if I select the `yAxis2`, it is the `yAxis` which is dragged vertically.

I guess the problem is in axisRect() which is related only to the left yAxis rather than both of them.

Comment: Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by modifiying the code in order to perform the drag calls on the right axis as well.
It is pretty straightforward if one takes a look on what happens on the left axis.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get both `yAxis` and `yAxis2` to drag together by calling [`QCPAxisRect::setRangeDragAxes()`](https://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPAxisRect.html#ab756bc5f129115fa3e8783617292fc1a).

**Note:** If you still want the `xAxis` to drag with the mouse, then you need to have it in the list too because the defaults will get overwritten.

```
QList<QCPAxis *> draggableAxes = {xAxis,yAxis,yAxis2};
myPlot->axisRect()->setRangeDragAxes(draggableAxes);
```

If you want similar behavior for zoom interactions as well, there's a setter for that too! [`QCPAxisRect::setRangeZoomAxes()`](https://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPAxisRect.html#a07a41be4eda0d42abe49475e9fa38b92)